# Attach query result as excel in email without storing excel using ssis script task

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, script-task

I need to send query result of table as excel attachment in email using SSIS script task.I don't want to store excel as it will be in my production server.
Can we send query result from table as abc.csv/abc.xls attachment over email.

Can anyone help with the code?

Comment: Nope, StackOverflow cannot help you write your code. That's not what this site exists for.

Comment: The biggest challenge when you're starting out or starting in a new language/environment is breaking the problem down into manageable pieces. It seems you've got a handle on what needs to happen (Run a query with results, store results in table-like format (csv, excel, etc), send email, send email with attachments). Each one of those steps has multiple answers on this site, moreover the many solutions across the internet just a search engine away. Refine your question, distill it down to the piece that you can't get or that is yielding incorrect results. Then show us the work so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Just some hints:

1. You have to pass your query results as a RecordSet variable to the script task.
2. Then, in the script task's code, you convert the contents of this RecordSet to a CSV, writing to a `Stream` (most likely a `MemoryStream`).
3. Assuming you use the `SmtpClient` class to send the email, you can then pass the `Stream` to the constructor of the `Attachment` class which you add to the `MailMessage` instance that represents your email.